# What should I do to recognize digits from an seven segment display?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing

I'am working on a project to take pictures of the electricity meter reading and process the image to recognize the numbers and upload it to the cloud.

```
   import cv2
   import numpy as np
   from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
   from PIL import Image 


   image = cv2.imread('meter1.jpg')
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   cv2.imshow('Original image',image)


   cv2.imshow('Gray image', gray)

   threshold = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 83, 5) 
   cv2.imshow('Adaptive Gaussian', threshold) 

   cv2.imwrite('Binary.png',threshold)

   cv2.waitKey(0)
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is the code I have written so far which converts RGB image to grayscale and then used adaptive thresholding

[This the image I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRWDp.jpg)

What should I do next? Should I use tesseract OCR ? What are the ways to extract these digits or numbers

[This is the image I got after running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjps1.png)

Please help on how to proceed from this stage

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-classification-plot-digits-classification-py

Comment: If it is always that same 7-segment display, with a very limited *"font"*, you should be able to use *"template matching"* very accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Just check a point (or mean of a small ROI inside a segment) in each segment to recognize which digit is displayed.

Comment: what's an ROI in this context?

Comment: Small rectangular region entirely placed inside a segment. Region Of Interest .